# nice and clean android scroll like this? (with image)

Tags: android, android-styles, android-scroll, android-scrollbar

How do I get my android scrollbars looking like this? (see image link).
... I am working on my first Android app. Am new to android and sometimes the simplest things can bee a challenge. Can anyone please point me the right direction. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scrollbars look slightly different on every device, and especially for every version of the Android OS.

**I suggest that you leave them exactly as they are by default.**

Your scrollbar will look different, perhaps just like in your example, depending on the device in which you test your application.

I think your application will look better and support your users more professionally if the scrollbars look and behave exactly like all of the other scrollbars in all of the other apps on their device.

In terms of customization, you can add an infinite number of modifications regarding thumb scrollers, fast scrolling, showing horizontal and vertical tracks, scroll themes, etc. Check out [android:scrollbarStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3ascrollbarStyle) and other parameters at that link.